# Return value in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has an if statement in it. If the number of rows counted is greater than 0 then it should set the only output parameter `@UserId` to 0

However it only returns a value in the second part of the query.

```
@EmailAddress varchar(200),
@NickName varchar(100),
@Password varchar(150),
@Sex varchar(50),
@Age int,
@EmailUpdates int,
@UserId int OUTPUT
IF 
    (SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM RegUsers WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @UserId = 0
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO RegUsers (EmailAddress,NickName,PassWord,Sex,Age,EmailUpdates) VALUES (@EmailAddress,@NickName,@Password,@Sex,@Age,@EmailUpdates)
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

END
```

Comment: What do you mean by "returns a value in the second part of the query"? Output parameter won't be returned as a recordset

Answer (score 9):

You can either do 1 of the following:

Change:

`SET @UserId` = 0 to `SELECT @UserId`

This will return the value in the same way your 2nd part of the IF statement is.

---

Or, seeing as @UserId is set as an Output, change:

`SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to `SET @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

---

It depends on how you want to access the data afterwards. If you want the value to be in your result set, use `SELECT`. If you want to access the new value of the @UserId parameter afterwards, then use `SET @UserId`

---

Seeing as you're accepting the 2nd condition as correct, the query you could write (without having to change anything outside of this query) is:

```
@EmailAddress varchar(200),
@NickName varchar(100),
@Password varchar(150),
@Sex varchar(50),
@Age int,
@EmailUpdates int,
@UserId int OUTPUT
IF 
    (SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM RegUsers WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT 0
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO RegUsers (EmailAddress,NickName,PassWord,Sex,Age,EmailUpdates) VALUES (@EmailAddress,@NickName,@Password,@Sex,@Age,@EmailUpdates)
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

END
```

Comment: Hi Ive tried setting the second part to set the @UserId but that didnt work either

Comment: @andrewslaughter See my edit. Both conditions are now using `SELECT`, which will return a value in your result set. Looking at your question, it seems thats how you are accessing the value from this query

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend make pre-init of future index value, this is very usefull in a lot of case like multi work, some export e.t.c.

just create additional `User_Seq` table:
with two fields: `id Uniq index` and `SeqVal nvarchar(1)`

and create next SP, and generated ID value from this SP and put to new User row!

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[User_NextValue]
as
begin
    set NOCOUNT ON


    declare @existingId int = (select isnull(max(UserId)+1, 0)  from dbo.User)

    insert into User_Seq (SeqVal) values ('a')
    declare @NewSeqValue int = scope_identity()     

    if @existingId > @NewSeqValue 
    begin  

        set identity_insert User_Seq  on
        insert into User_Seq (SeqID) values (@existingId)     
        set @NewSeqValue = scope_identity()     
    end

    delete from User_Seq WITH (READPAST)

return @NewSeqValue

end
```

Comment: by the MSDN there is an advice: *Also you should avoid using the return code to return application data.*

Answer (score 2):

Try to call your proc in this way:

```
DECLARE @UserIDout int

EXEC YOURPROC @EmailAddress = 'sdfds', @NickName = 'sdfdsfs', ..., @UserId = @UserIDout OUTPUT

SELECT @UserIDout
```

Comment: @AndreyGurinov I don't see how this would solve the problem.. UserId will still be NULL for the 2nd condition.

Comment: Hi thanks for that

If I ExecuteStoredProcedure from the object explorer and put the parameters in 

the first time I run it, I get in the results pane

(no column name) 64 (this is the last insert user id)
&amp;UserId NULL
Return Value 0

If I then run it again I just get 

&amp;UserId 0
return value 0

Comment: This helped me figure out how to call the stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

```
@EmailAddress varchar(200),
@NickName varchar(100),
@Password varchar(150),
@Sex varchar(50),
@Age int,
@EmailUpdates int,
@UserId int OUTPUT
DECLARE @AA INT
SET @AA=(SELECT COUNT(UserId) FROM RegUsers WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress)

IF @AA> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @UserId = 0
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO RegUsers (EmailAddress,NickName,PassWord,Sex,Age,EmailUpdates) VALUES (@EmailAddress,@NickName,@Password,@Sex,@Age,@EmailUpdates)
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END

END
```